# Create column based upon cutoffs

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be simple, but I can't figure out the easiest way to do this.  I want to reduce columns to a simpler range.  Take the following dataset:

```
white    black
2000     2100
2050     2000
2100     2200
2150     2300
2240     2240
2300     2550
2400     2450
2500     2150
2850     2000
```

I would like to create a new column white$rank and black$rank where numerical ranges 2000-2100 get a value of 1, 2100-2200 get a value of 2, and so on.

```
 white_rank black_rank
    0     1
    0     0
    1     2
    1     3
    2     2
    3     5
    4     4
    5     1
    8     0
```

I get that I can achieve this via something like 
white_class <- substr(df$white, 2, 2)

But I wanted a more flexible solution where I could make white_rank take any value.  The basic idea is to generate a sequence for demarcating cutoffs `seq(2000,2900, 100)` and then assigning unique values depending on if a row meets those cutoffs.

Comment: please search the cut function

Comment: yes, something like this:                                                                   
`df$rank <- cut(variable, breaks = c(seq(2000, 3000, 100)), labels=0:9)
df[is.na(df)] <- 0`

Comment: perfect.  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can create ranges with the `cut()` function as follows.

```
rawData <- "white    black
2000     2100
2050     2000
2100     2200
2150     2300
2240     2240
2300     2550
2400     2450
2500     2150
2850     2000"

theData <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE)
# count the bins 
levelsWhite <- round((max(theData$white) - min(theData$white))/100,0)+1
levelsBlack <- round((max(theData$black) - min(theData$black))/100,0)+1
theData$whiteFactor <- cut(theData$white,levelsWhite,labels=FALSE,right=FALSE)
theData$blackFactor <- cut(theData$black,levelsBlack,labels=FALSE,right=FALSE)
theData
```

The output looks like this.

```
> theData
  white black whiteFactor blackFactor
1  2000  2100           1           2
2  2050  2000           1           1
3  2100  2200           2           3
4  2150  2300           2           4
5  2240  2240           3           3
6  2300  2550           4           6
7  2400  2450           5           5
8  2500  2150           6           2
9  2850  2000           9           1
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and the `cut` function from base R. The idea is to use `cut` to create factors and then use `levels<-` to assign new level names. I used `mutate_all` from the `dplyr` to perform this operation for all columns.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate_all(funs(cut(., breaks = seq(2000, 2900, by = 100), right = FALSE, dig.lab = 1))) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(`levels<-`(., value = 0:8)))
# dt2
#   white black
# 1     0     1
# 2     0     0
# 3     1     2
# 4     1     3
# 5     2     2
# 6     3     5
# 7     4     4
# 8     5     1
# 9     8     0
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "white    black
2000     2100
2050     2000
2100     2200
2150     2300
2240     2240
2300     2550
2400     2450
2500     2150
2850     2000",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is very clever.  Thanks a bunch